# Input a special string during runtime in C

Tags: c, string, input

In my C code I am given the following string as input:

```
"c:\tc\bin\a c j k.jpg"
```

I tried to read the input with scanf but it failed (passing the input both with and without quotation marks) and I am looking for an other solution.

My code is as follows:

```
char keytext[16],zzz,source[100],dest[100];
short int a;
size_t readcount;

clrscr();
printf("input the key text(max 16 characters):");
scanf("%s",&keytext);

printf("input file name:");
scanf("%s",&source);

/*fgets(source,100,stdin);
namelen=strlen(source);
if(source[namelen-1]=='\n')
source[namelen-1]='\0';*/

printf("output file name:");
scanf("%s",&dest);
```

Comment: Is `C:\tc\bin\a c j k.jpg` to be treated as a single string?

Comment: Can you give us more detailed explanation?

Comment: @hmjd yes as am going to read that file's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specifier `%s` will stop consuming input when the first whitespace character is encountered, so it will only read until the end of `C:\tc\bin\a`. To read up to the `k.jpg` you can use a scanset:

```
char input[128];
if (1 == scanf("%127[^\n]", input))
{
}
```

The format specifier `"%127[^\n]"` means read up to the next newline character but no more than 127 characters to prevent buffer overrun. You should check the return value of `scanf()` before using its output, it returns the number of assignments made.

Comment: what about the characters \t and \b and \a in that string

Comment: The are not part of a string literal, they are input so will be copied into the `input` array.

Comment: come on you have used sscanf on ideone and gave scanf in here, how could i come to know about that

Comment: @user1026137, I had to use `sscanf()` on ideone as there is no way to provide input (AFAIK). However, `sscanf()` uses the same format specifiers as `scanf()`, the only difference being the source of input. See reference page for [`sscanf()` and `scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` function with `%s` specificator expects pointer to char `char *`. But you pass the pointer to pointer to char  `char **`.
In order to fix it use the following code instead:

```
scanf("%s", keytext);
scanf("%s", source);
scanf("%s", dest);
```

Note, it doesn't require `&` symbol.
If you want to read whole string with spaces, you can use `fgets` function.

```
fgets(keytext, sizeof(keytext), stdin);
fgets(source,  sizeof(source),  stdin);
fgets(dest,    sizeof(dest),    stdin);
```

Comment: But that will not solve OP question of scanning with white spaces.

Comment: @fasked if i use fgets after doing the first input using scanf, it won't work at all.

Comment: @user1026137 I got you! After using `scanf` stream keeps `\n` symbol. You need to clear the stream. Try to `scanf("%*[^\n]")` before `fgets`.

Comment: @user1026137 it seems we just don't understand your problem